# Excel: how to merge two tables of data?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, merge

I have two sheets with two tables of data and I'd like to merge them into a single one like this:

[image: https://goo.gl/eJdy8M]

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Make your tables one table. Do this by removing the blank lines and the header of the second table. Create a pivot table. Do the following:

- Date in Rows
- Category in Columns
- Qty and Total in Values
- Design Tab -> Grand Totals -> Off for Rows and Columns